# Store SQS messages in S3 Bucket as a CSV format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

**Hi everyone,**

In my Amazon SQS, I have messages in the format of Key-Value(around 10 keys-10 values in each message), keys are repeated in every message in the queue, only the value change.

I want to build a CSV file from that messages and store them in an S3 bucket, I have tried a Lambda function but I am still can't find a way to do it, could anybody help me with that, please?

Best Regards

Comment: What's exactly wrong with your lambda function?

Comment: What API are you using in a Lambda function to make this work. You can use a given AWS SDK within a Lambda function, read the messages in a SQS queue, format the data to CSV, and then use the S3 API to place the content into an Amazon S3 bucket.

Comment: I am stuck with this error:     "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied",

Comment: I have added a policy that contains "PutObject" in s3 bucket permission but still the same error